# elasticsearch nested query does not give proper result

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Hi I am having a problem, we are building a help system where user can search the help content. I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "com.mycompany.content": {
    "mappings": {
      "pageMasterContent": {
        "properties": {
          "contentType": {
            "type": "string",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "include_in_all": true
          },
          "customer": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "class": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "customerName": {
                "type": "string",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "include_in_all": true
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "ref": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              }
            }
          },
          "language": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "class": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "langName": {
                "type": "string",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "ref": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              }
            }
          },
          "pageContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "include_in_all": true
          },
          "pageMaster": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "class": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "pageCode": {
                "type": "string",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "include_in_all": true
              },
              "pageSinceVersion": {
                "properties": {
                  "class": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "versionNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "versionOrder": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "pageUptoVersion": {
                "properties": {
                  "class": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "versionNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "versionOrder": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "ref": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              }
            }
          },
          "pageVersion": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "class": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "ref": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "versionNumber": {
                "type": "string",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "include_in_all": true
              },
              "versionOrder": {
                "type": "integer",
                "include_in_all": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to filter my data with following parameters:

`language`, `pageSinceVersion` and `pageUptoVersion` where, if a user searches for any content it should show only for that language and for >`pageSinceVersion` and <`pageUptoVersion` content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your search template which is not giving proper results?

Comment: @jay : Hi I am using the following query: *{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "language",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "language.langName": "English"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}*